# estimation for n-th prime

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory

The famous theorem of Hadamard and Vallee-Poussin
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem
implies that $p_n\sim n\ln n$, so $C_1 n\ln n \le p_n \le C_2 n\ln n$ holds for all $n\ge 2$ with some constants $C_1,C_2$.

Since $p_n\sim n\ln n$, we obviously have $C_1\le 1$.

I found somewhere in the internet (I don't remember the exact source) that $C_1=1$ and $C_2=29$ works fine.

How these values were derived?

Is $C_2=29$ optimal or a smaller value is known?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The lower bound, that $n \log n < p_n$ was proved by Rosser in 1938, and is sometimes called [Rosser's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rosser%27s_theorem).

For upper bounds, the indisputable expert is Pierre Dusart, who has several results revolving around explicit bounds related to the sizes of primes and collections of primes. He proved that
$$ p_n < n \log n + n \log \log n$$
for $n \geq 6$. In particular, $n \log \log n < n \log n$, so the bound $C_2 = 2$ should be fine for $n \geq 6$. If you are interested in particular for the bound holding for all $n \geq 2$, then it's just a matter of checking for $n \leq 5$. A quick numeric check indicates that $C_2 \approx 2.16405$ suffices for $n \geq 2$.

Comment: Also see Axler 2013, as well as both Dusart 2010 and Dusart 1999.  There is a range where each of Dusart 1999 p 14; Dusart 2010 pg 7; Dusart 2010 pg 2; and Axler 2013 Kor G  give the best results (Axler's is best for values over 8,009,824).